# missing .cs files in precompiled website with c# in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web, precompiled, c#

I need to change the code of some asp.net application but the application is missing its .cs files, there are only .aspx files. As I read in google, I understand that the application is a precompiled website. I am not too familiar with it so the question is, can I somehow retrieve the code-behind .cs files of this application because I need to change some functions there. Surely there is a way I can access them or retrieve them somehow?

Thanks in advance,

Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a precompiled website, you will not be able to access the original .cs files. They are compiled into assemblies, that you will find in the bin folder. If you cannot get the original .cs files from somewhere; then you can try using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) for reading the code. Just keep in mind that what you are seeing through Reflector will be *equivalent* code, not the *original* code.

Answer (score 1):

If the website's code was compiled into a DLL, and that DLL was written in C# or VB.NET, you can probably decompile the DLL. Is that what you mean?

**Edit:** @driis gives the link to Reflector that I was thinking of. I've used it when I lost some code, it works.

Comment: I think so..There are some dll's there, do you mean app_Code.dll which is locatated in the bin directory? the How can I decompile it?